# Is there a reason to avoid traveling into Rome on Easter Sunday/Monday?

Tags: trains, rome, public-holidays, easter

I do not observe Easter, but may be traveling to Rome around Easter Sunday/Monday.

I do not plan on going to the Vatican, but on the day of my arrival I would fly in, take the express train to Termini Station, take a cab to my lodging. And then I would want to walk around the city (no need for museums), get a bite to eat in the Jewish Ghetto area.

Is there a reason to specifically avoid traveling into Rome on either of these two days (Easter Sunday or Monday, which is also a national holiday in Italy)? Or a reason to prefer one day over the other (or even different times of day - for example, "it is fine to arrive on the morning of Easter Sunday, but avoid the evening")?

What I have seen so far in my research is that there should be an expectation of more places being closed, public transportation being less reliable (no idea if this extends to scheduled express trains from the airport or not). And that Monday might be a day when many Romans will leave the city for family outings (so maybe not the best day to travel)?

Looking for insights from anyone with firsthand experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around Easter you can expect a large influx of people interested in the religious celebrations in San Pietro. This might result in larger crowds in Piazza San Pietro and higher rates/less availability for accommodation.

Additionally on the Monday, due to most people leaving the city in the morning and returning in the evening, you might expect traffic congestion in the outbound/inbound direction respectively.

That apart there is no particular reason for avoiding it: Rome is packed with tourists every day.

Comment: I was also concerned about the affect of Easter being both a religious and national holiday affecting things in an unusual way for travel logistics.